# DirectSound - how to get started

Tags: c#

I need to use the direct sound librarys for my C# application.

Do I need to download a SDK and install?

Are the libraries already installed as part of windows xp sp3?

In C# under references I just include microsoft.directsound?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DirectSound is part of the DirectX SDK. So this means writing C++ or C# with Wrapper classes, or using XNA for C#, since there is no managed DirectX any more.

Microsoft is currently pushing for XACT, which is a higher level library that allows developers to write for the XBOX360 and Windows. It uses XAudio2 on the XBOX and DirectSound on Windows.

Comment: The managed DirectX, whilst deprecated, is still available e.g. from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/directx/aa937788.aspx